# How can I access network statistics (like bandwith/data usage) in logs for the past 2 weeks?

Tags: networking, log, system-monitor, network-monitoring, bandwidth

I want to extract network statistics of past two weeks. It should contain information like the uploads and downloads, also the network speed (bandwith ) I received.

I tried system monitor, but unfortunately, it just shows in realtime and clears up the log after shutdown. I also tried going through /var/log/ but I'm clueless as to in which file is the network statistics for past week would be stored.

(PS: I know this is unusual. Read the full story if you're interested. I use vodafone's 3G dongle. I activated some extra plans on my a/c and never recieved an activation sms. Neither was I able to use the pack at boosted speed (for which I paid).  I am tired of talking to my service providers and they claim I the pack was activated when in fact I did not received a confirmation SMS or an increased speed (which happens after you activate a booster pack after consuming your basic plan ).   The softwares they use seem to be shit. I need to send this info to them or contact consumer forum to file a complaint against service providers. )

Comment: Do you have pepperflash? What do "check my bandwidth" sites report?

Comment: @geoffmcc Thanks. I already have been using Cairo Dock with the widget "netspeed" for months. It shows net speed in real time. It basically links to system monitor where I can monitor network too. I don't have pepperflash.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let me dissect your analysis.

> "they [The ISPs] claim I am getting good speed"...

What they claim is based on your up/down speed you pay for and their tests from their equipment to your modem in all likelihood.  Their test is likely right - the speed at your modem is okay - but the issue might lie *behind* that, such as your router not operating efficiently or something.  It could also be your computer isn't functioning as it should be or has something running that eats your system resources.

> ... "when in fact I am not"

Basis for analysis?  Have you removed your router from the equation and hooked your internet right up to your computer over the ethernet connection?  If you have and you're still getting crap speeds, next thing to check is your computer. And run the same test via another computer if you can.

Also, your internet service providers are *not* required to guarantee you your advertised speeds.  I have a 105 Mbps downspeed connection from Comcast here, and I get about 85 Mbps on an average day, likely due to data usage and congestion on the line from the other Comcast users in the area all on at once.

---

Now onto your issues.  I don't know of any log system that actually logs by-the-minute network connection speeds, because it's likely that they don't exist.  Such logs would be on a network level at your router, if anywhere, or would overload your computer.

I use `vnstat` to get at-a-glance data in/out statistics, such as daily / monthly usage, however that won't help you get your per-upload, per-download, and total bandwidth speeds.  What you'd be seeking there is something such as [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net/)'s speed testing tool, which I would recommend you run on the internet connection itself, without a router present and the computer hooked right in.

Again, though, your ISP may *advertise* one speed, but that's never a guaranteed speed.

`ntop` is also a possible alternative to use, it runs as a system daemon and you can access a web-based interface to see pretty graphics and statistics.  However, it might not be the statistics you are fully after.

Comment: I have been using a 3G dongle by Vodafone as I was travelling for weeks to come.
I also use cairo dock and use "netspeed" widget which displays current net speed. That's why I was wondering if it gets stored in some logs as I noticed in /var/logs/
Also, over the conversation with them, I suspected their softwares might be screwed. They say I won't be able to activate same booster pack twice, I already did. They say that a new booster pack is already active, its not. I will pay for it, but I am not getting to use it. And also, that booster pack is not even listed in my online a/c.Its annoying!

Comment: I made some edits in my question details to give more clarity. Thanks for your answer. You are right. But I needed logs of past. Not present. Sorry for misunderstanding. Also, the steps you suggested don't apply in my case as I am using a dongle. I uploaded a screenshot of search results for "network" in /var/logs/ here http://i.imgur.com/V2mxYYk.png?1

Comment: Alsom check out this link http://linux.about.com/od/lna_guide/a/gdelna137.htm
It says that there is some stats log file. I don't know how to access that.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ntop

Ntop will run in background as a service. You can check results in browser.

Comment: I suggest your question you ask here be moved to comments against the question - at first glance the quesiton here makes the answer appear as "not an answer".